# Twitter tweet widget - text only?

Tags: javascript, twitter

How can l have the text only tweet from the twitter widget?

All [widgets](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines) seem come with picture-based tweets. Eg.

```html
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-height="800" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev">Tweets by TwitterDev</a> <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

But I don't have the pictures - just info. Is it possible?

Comment: Capture the output in a function before it's displayed and strip out the <img> tags.

Comment: @Difster can you provide a rough example please?